# Xcode project templates: How can I specify a static library dependency?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-template

I am trying to create an Xcode project template that contains two compilable targets, with one target (an app) dependent on the other (a static lib).

Everything works so far, except that I cannot figure out how to specify the actual dependency in the template so that it shows up in the Target Dependencies section of the Build Phases tab of the app target of an Xcode project created from the template.

I've configured the TemplateInfo.plist of the project as follows:

[image: TemplateInfo.plist of project containing static lib dependency]

The Components section identifies the static library project template and successfully brings the contents of that template, and its target, into the app project. And once everything is compiled, the static library is successfully linked in the end, by Item 3 in the OTHER_LDFLAGS entry.

But try as I might, the Dependencies section of the template does not cause the static lib to appear in the Target Dependencies section of the Build Phases tab of the app target. I've tried specifying the dependency using the numeric values 0 and 1, and I've tried it as a string using the name of the static library target (cocos2d), but none of these work.

In the end, in each Xcode project created from this template, I'm left with users having to perform the step of navigating to the Target Dependencies section of the Build Phases tab of the app target, and manually selecting and adding the static library target. Although this is a relatively simple task, it shouldn't be necessary at all.

Can anyone advise me on how to configure the template dependencies so this manual step is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

As you've indicated, the *Dependancies* tag under *Targets* references target array indices. In the example you've posted, your dependency is under *Components*.

Components appear to be add as targets after the targets from your template file are added to the project. If you reference the *Cocoa Touch Application* template provided with Xcode, *Cocoa Touch Application Unit Testing Bundle* is included as a component.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Temlpates/Application

[image: Cocoa Touch Application - TemplateInfo.plist]

Looking at the plist for the *Cocoa Touch Application Unit Testing Bundle*, there is a dependency on target 0. Given components appear to be added after "local" targets, target 0 is 
present in the project when the unit test target is added and a dependency is created against the primary target.

[image: Cocoa Touch Application Unit Testing Bundle - TemplateInfo.plist]

Attempting this in reverse by adding a dependency on target 1 in the *Cocoa Touch Application* does not work.

The only work around that I've been able to find is to move *Components* to *Ancestors* and duplicate the *Targets* items from each component in the *Targets* section of your template. From there you can reference the indices of any components included in your targets array.

You should note that even with this technique, targets appear to be added to the project in order and you only seem to be able to set dependancies on indices that have already been added (i.e. index 0 cannot reference index 2).